# Show Different "Code/Words" Based on URL Referer

Tags: php

I'm trying to have my website not show certain code if they come from certain URL's.

For example, Wikipedia don't like links to sites that have popups on them. So I need to not show the code for that referer.

I found the following code but it doesn't seem to work when code is places instead of text

```
<?php $ref=getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
if (strpos($ref,"google.com")>0) 
{
echo "google";

}
else
{
echo "something else";
};
?>
```

Comment: Bare in mind you'd have to come from google for that code to work, did you try it that way? Also you don't need a `;` after the last `}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid showing code to google:

```
<?php if (!strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),"googlebot")){ ?>
  //Show what you want, google will not see it 
}else{
       //show other code
  }?>?>
```

For wikipedia:

```
<?php if (!strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),"wikipedia")){ ?>
      //Show what you want, wikipedia will not see it 
 }else{
       //show other code
  }?>
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: he wants referer, not user agent

Comment: @genesisφ: Updated the code, referer included in 2nd example for wikipedia.

Comment: OK, great. What happens if I want to show different code though?

Comment: @Rhys: You put it in the else part ;)

Answer (score 0):

You were talking about Wikipedia. Probably the problem is that google isn't sending you "google" in their referer string

Comment: That's just placeholder text from the example. Shouldn't have put that really.

Answer (score 0):

it must work, try alternative variable

```
<?php
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($ref,"google.com")>0) 
{
echo "google";

}
else
{
echo "something else";
};
?>
```

Comment: This works when using words, but put code inside the echo "something else"; It won't show up.

Comment: remove semicolon from second last line and test again